# Cocoa- Using representedObject for NSButton in NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

**Setup**

I have a `NSCollectionView`. I have a checkbox in the `View Prototype`. I've successfully set up bindings so the `Card Title` and `action` get populated. (image 1, below)

**Goal**

I'd like, when I click the checkbox, to run a function that accesses the specific `CardModel` that the `View Prototype` is already able to access. I'll then manipulate its data accordingly.

**Research**

I found this article on SO: [Get the representedObject values of NSCollectionViewItem NSButton click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468789/get-the-representedobject-values-of-nscollectionviewitem-nsbutton-click), which describes my situation pretty well. The answer, unfortunately, is without specific code. Here's what's suggested:

> So, first, set the represented object of your button's cell to the
>   collection view item that owns the button. (You can do this in the nib
>   editor.) Then, in your action method, get the button's cell, then the
>   cell's represented object (which is the item), then the item's
>   represented object.

Seems simple enough, right?

**Attempted Solution(s)**

I create a method `cardCheckBoxClicked:` and connect it to the checkbox.

As per the advice above, I connect the `button cell`'s outlet `representedObject` to `Card Collection View Item`. (image 2)

I then attempt to get the `Card Collection View Item`'s `representedObject` in code.

From `MainWindowController.h`:

```
-(IBAction)cardCheckBoxClicked:(id)sender
{
    CardModel* cModel = [[sender representedObject] representedObject];

    NSLog(@"card title: %@",cModel.title);
}
```

**Error**

When I click on the checkbox, I get the following error:

```
-[NSButton representedObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001581b0
```

**Question!**

So - *how do I* access the `button cell`'s represented object? Did I misunderstand the advice given above? How can I successfully access the data I need?

**Images (reference)**

bindings example
[image]

represented object connection
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here:

```
-[NSButton representedObject]:
```

Is you asking the Class NSButton to run the method representedObject. Make sure you distinguish between a Class an an object or instance of that class.

You need to take the actual button, get its button cell, (at least I think that's what you want), and then call representedObject on the cell. If I am understanding you correctly. I never touch interface builder, so here's completely made up code that lines up with what you are asking for.

```
someObject = [[theButton cell] representedObject];
```

Comment: This is essentially correct. For the particular case in the question, he wants `CardModel* cModel = [[[sender cell] representedObject] representedObject];`.

Comment: ah - the [sender cell] bit did it. From Apple's NSButton class reference docs, I got the impression that I didn't need to deal with the cell, and that NSButton would "take care" of things accordingly.

Comment: for general SO-friendliness, should I edit my question down to the bare minimum part of my code that was causing the issue? Or is it advisable to leave as-is, with extraneous details included?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CH Buckingham's answer, you should also consider using bindings. You can bind the checkbox's value binding to the collection view item with a model key path which goes through `representedObject` to some property on your `CardModel`. (If desired, the key path can keep going through your model object graph.) That will set that property whenever the button is toggled.

Comment: Ken, my current implementation requires the checkbox to call a function, doing more than toggling a property. I agree that bindings are a cleaner and easier way to access my `CardModel` data, and implemented them where possible already.

Comment: Toggling a property ***is*** calling a method. Specifically, the property's setter.